# I get SIGSEGV error while I trying the debug the exe file on mackBook Pro Intel

Tags: segmentation-fault

[image]

I tried a lot of things, but I cannot find any usefull information. Can the error related to macOs?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, why would the error relate to macOS? Do you get the SIGSEV *only* when running the program inside gdb, or does it also occur when running the program directly (i.e. `./a.out`)?

Comment: SIGSEV, or "Segment Violstion: is caused by an out-of-bounds memory reference,  to location 0, pointer error, or executing data.